# Is it possible to decide where menu is drawn next to pie button?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, pie-menu

I would like the menu to showup left to the pie button and not right. Is that possible?

```
    pie.menu("edge.menu2", text="Edge Menu")
```

[image]

Comment: I think it can work if [edge menu] is also a pie menu. Then, in a pie you can further decide the position of a certain item or menu.  But this may be too much here.

Comment: wait you mean draw a new mini pie over the current master pie?

Comment: pies can contain items, menus or pies. never tried myself so I'm not sure it's the answer, but yeah that's the idea